# Extracting text from div tags within a div?

Tags: html, css, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the text from within the div tag (Refer Code) (that is I need to extract "Stackoverflow  to your rescue!")

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
            <div class="four">
                <div class="five"> 
                    <div class="text_desc">               
                        <p itemprop="description">
                            <p> 
                                <div> 
                                    Stackoverflow to your rescue!
                                </div>     
                            </p>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to scrape using scrapy in python, but I don't understand why `response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="text_desc"]').extract()` returns an empty list. So I'm unable to write queries to extract the text. Tell me how should I go about it! (A solution using cssSelectors would also do)

Comment: Additionally, I would also like to know, what parent element should my xpath query start with?

Comment: Do you want to get the text to give some styling or diff purpose??

Comment: I just need to extract the text, without worrying about the styling.

Comment: Your xpath is fine - `'//div[@class="text_desc"]//text()'` should extract all text nodes under `<div class="text_desc">` node. Are you sure the source you are getting matches your example?

Comment: @Granitosaurus Well `response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="article_text_desc"]//text()').extract()` does the job. Thanks! But, I didn't understand why `xpath('//div[@class="article_text_desc"]').extract()` was returning an empty list.

Comment: Because it was only returning the div and not the child elements, specifically the text you were looking for.  `//text()` appended to your xpath told it to look for all text at any level beyond (inside) that division.

Comment: @BillHileman I thought `xpath('//div[@class="article_text_desc"]').extract()` was suppose to return the entire contents of the corresponding div.

Comment: I have no first-hand experience with scrapy, but since the xpath only points to the division, I would think that .extract() would only return the text or contents on that node level, not from children nodes.  Since you can alter the xpath to tell it to include child nodes of type text, there was probably no reason for the designers to make that an option, therefore allowing the programmer to be specific using the xpath.  Only my guess.